# How can i link current node to next node?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Example I want to add 5 different node. When i click 1st node i want to see pager (1 of 5) When i click next it will go to next node page. Look at here http://transcribe.archives.gov/content/communication-relating-katyn-forest-massacre

there is a different contents no one paged content. It is Drupal Transcribr distrubiton. How can i make that pager my Drupal site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Drupal's `Book module`. It's a core module.

Drupal.org documentation uses `Book module`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the Previous/Next API module:

http://drupal.org/project/prev_next